# Can I write (x86) assembly language which will build with both GCC and MSVC?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, assembly, nasm

I have a project which is entirely written in C. The same C files can be compiled using either GCC for Linux or MSVC for Windows. For performance reasons, I need to re-write some of the code as x86 assembly language.

Is it possible to write this assembly language as a source file which will build with both the GCC and MSVC toolchains? Alternatively, if I write an assembly source file for one toolchain, is there a tool to convert it to work with the other?

Or, am I stuck either maintaining two copies of the assembly source code, or using a third-party assembler such as [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/)?

Comment: Are you asking because you triend and failed or because you investigated and did not find a definitive answer? Are you aware of calling convention differences - if there are any - between these two?

Comment: Are we talking about 32 bit or 64 bit assembly?

Comment: Inline assembly or not?

Comment: @RadLexus - I investigated, but have not yet found a way to create a single source file compatible with both toolchains. I will look into calling convention differences.

Comment: @FUZxxl - 32-bit at present, but probably 64-bit in the near future.

Comment: @Banex - I was not thinking of inline assembly, but whatever works...

Comment: If the only difference is the calling conventions, you'd typically write either separate headers, or use `#ifdef` to determine the platform. (Of course only practical if you are not going to do system calls, i.e., use assembler for computations only.)

Comment: @RadLexus - Using the assembly language equivalent of `#ifdef` to work around calling convention differences makes sense. However, a bigger difference between the toolchains seems to be assembler directives - does an `#ifdef` equivalent which works with both assemblers even exist?

Comment: Sorry, I supposed you were using C wrappers for your assembler. Do you intend to include your assembled object files instead?

Comment: @RadLexus - _"C wrappers for your assembler"_ - as in inline assembly?

Comment: No, just wrappers for the C functions that call your assembly code. They would typically reside in header files and be adjusted for the correct calling convention. Which begs the question: Is your assembler code in separate object files, or are you writing all of it as inline code?

Comment: @RadLexus - I was planning to write assembly language in separate source files and assemble these into separate object files, which can then be linked with the existing C code. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "C wrappers" - could you please give an example? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [libjpeg-turbo's approach to the same problem](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo), which is to use NASM.

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems:

- masm and gas have different syntax. gas can be configured to use Intel syntax with the `.syntax intel,noprefix` directive, but even then small differences remain (such as, different directives). A possible approach is to preprocess your assembly source with the C preprocessor, using macros for all directives that differ between the two. This also has the advantage of providing a unified comment syntax.

  However, just using a portable third party assembler like nasm is likely to be less of a hassle.
- Linux and Windows have different calling conventions. A possible solution for x86-32 is to stick to a well-supported calling convention like `stdcall`. You can tell gcc what calling convention to use when calling a function using [*function attributes*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes). For example, this would declare `foo` to use the `stdcall` calling convention:

  ```
  extern int foo(int x, int y) __attribute__((stdcall));
  ```

  You can do the same thing in MSVC with `__declspec`, solving this issue.

  On x86-64, a similar solution is likely possible, but I'm not exactly sure what attributes you have to set.

  You can of course also use the same cpp-approach as for the first problem to generate slightly different function prologues and epilogues depending on what calling convention you need. However, this might be less maintainable.

Comment: On 32-bit x86 it would make more sense to stick with the default "cdecl" calling convention, which is the same on both Linux on Windows.

Comment: So, would your recommendation be to use a third-party assembler? Is that how other projects (which contain assembly language and support multiple operating systems) usually solve this problem?

Comment: @user200783 Mostly by having C code to fall back on when a given CPU isn't supported or a given assembler isn't available.

Comment: @user200783 My recommendation is definitely to use a third party assembler. And then, what Ross Ridge says applies, i.e. provide an implementation in C, too. This is both for testing and for when you want to port your code to another architecture.